# How to access javascript variable in jsp within the same page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

table.jsp

```
        <script type="application/javascript">
        var ad="image/a11.png";
        var i=0;
        var j;
            function changeImage(a){
        j=document.getElementById(a);


           if(i===0){
          alert("click ok to seat");

      j.value=a;
      alert("j= "+j);
              document.getElementById(a).src = ad;
           //trying to access div with id 'seat'
             window.location.href='#seat?seat='+a;//won't works
             }
             i=i+1;
             }
           </script>
      </head>

      <body>
          <div id="frame">
        <img src="image/seatf.png"  id="1" onclick="changeImage('1')" title="Seat1"  />
     <div style="width:300;height:200;background-color:gray;" id="seat">
    <% 
    if(request.getParameter("seat")!=null){%>
    <h2> value is: <%= request.getParameter("seat") %> </h2>
    <% }%>
    </div>

    </div>
```

I'm unable to get the value of the parameter 'seat'.
 Is it the right way to achieve this?
If not, then how can I get the value of the parameter 'seat'?
Thanks..

Comment: I don't know JSP, is it like PHP and runs on the server? If so then to get info from the browser to the server one must use POST or GET, and they can do that using either XHR, link, form, etc. Are you opposed to using Javascript to conditionally display the "seat" parameter content?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, yes jsp is like php and runs on server but by default it uses GET.

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you want to accomplish?

```
<script>
var ad="image/a11.png";
var i=0;
var j;
function changeImage(j){
console.log(document.getElementById('seat').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML);
    if(i===0){
        document.getElementById(j.id).src = ad;
        document.getElementById('seat').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'value is: ' + j.id;
    }
    i+=1;
}
</script>

<div id="frame">
    <img src="image/seatf.png"  id="1" onclick="changeImage(this)" title="Seat1"  />
    <div style="width:300;height:200;background-color:gray;" id="seat">
        <h2> value is: ? </h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/w7NBa/